# How to refresh table UI on data change in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table in my asp.net project and i dynamically add some buttons to some cells at runtime. I add these buttons based on the data taken from the database. User chooses an item from dropdown list and clicks show schedule button and the table is filled. Here is some piece of my code:

```
 for (int i = startindex; i < endindex; i++)  
 {


  Button b = new Button();
  b.Text = subj + " " + numb + " " + section;
  b.Attributes.Add("onclick", "popWin()");
  b.CssClass = "roundedbuttons";

  Color clr = getCourseColor(subj + numb + section, courses);
  b.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
  b.Enabled = true;
  b.EnableViewState = true;
  b.UseSubmitBehavior = false;      
  b.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
  b.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
  string cellPosition = (i).ToString() + ";" + (dayindex).ToString();
  b.CommandArgument = cellPosition;
  table_row_click = true;                           

  table_filter_instructor_schedule.Rows[i].Cells[dayindex].Controls.Add(b);

  pageControls.Add(new PageControls(i, dayindex, null, subj + " " + numb + " " + section, "button"));

  visualTable = table_filter_instructor_schedule;

  }
```

And here is how the table looks like:

[image]

Then, at some point i update the database and change some data when user presses save changes button:

```
string selectedRooom = dropdown_available_rooms.SelectedValue.ToString();
        var values = selectedRooom.Split(' ');
        string newbldg = values[0], newroom = values[1];
        btnPopUp_ModalPopupExtender.Hide();
        //Update the database, and put the course to its new hours

        //term şimdilik
        SqlCommand commnd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Timetable SET starthour=@newstarthour, endhour=@newendhour, day=@newday, building=@newbuilding, room=@newroom WHERE subj=@subj AND numb=@numb AND section=@section AND term='201101' AND starthour=@starthour AND endhour=@endhour", CommonFunctions.con);
        commnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newstarthour", selected_new_starthour);
        commnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newendhour", selected_new_endhour);
        commnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newday", selected_new_day);
        commnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newbuilding", newbldg);
        commnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newroom", newroom);
        commnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subj", clicked_course_code);
        commnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numb", clicked_course_number);
        commnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", clicked_course_section);
        commnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starthour", clicked_course_starthour);
        commnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endhour", clicked_course_endhour);
        commnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Everything works fine until that point. The problem is, the changes are not reflected at the visual table, some buttons' positions(cells) have to change at the table. If i go to another page and then re open the page that has this visual table, table is updated and works fine. But after user clicks save changes button, the changes are not immediately seen at the table. The save changes button does not cause a postback even though causesValidation property is set to true. I somehow need to reload the page. I tried:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

after the data is updated, but this time the page is reloaded and naturally the table appears empty.

So, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You must recreat the table every time after the update.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply what I would recommend, based on what I think you are trying to do:

The code that the runs when you click "show schedule" should be placed into a Sub of its own. 
Call that Sub when the user clicks "show schedule". 
Then again call that Sub after the code to "save changes".

As far as this comment:

> The save changes button does not cause a postback even though
>   causesValidation property is set to true.

Are there update panels on your page? This could cause postback issues.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes there is a modal popup extender in my page, and save button is in that popup. Its onclick function is called and works, but no postback occurs

Comment: So there is a popup extender, but is there an update panel? it sounds like there is. is the table also inside of the popup, or just the save button?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the question I have for you. Are you creating these buttons dynamically? If so they will never fire the event. Here is why. If you do not create the buttons at the time the form is rendered or more to the point when the class (code behind file) is instantiated then the buttons will not connect with the fire or click event. You first need to create the buttons when the application starts or more directly when the Page_Load event fires. It doesn't matter how many you create as long as there are enough to go around when your application runs. So start with an array of Buttons and use a loop to create as many as you wish or need. Do this and add the attributes such as the click event name. I am posting some code below that will show you exactly how to do this. If you have any questions about anything I have posted here just ask.

```
  /* Place this above the Page_Load event */
  Button[] btnArray;

  /* Call this method or something similar to instantiate the buttons */
   private void InstantiateBtns()
    {
        //Instatiate every possible button needed for some purpose
        btnArray = new Button[1000];

        for (int i = 0; i < btnArray.Length; i++)
        {
            btnArray[i] = new Button();

            // sets the attributes for the button control
            btnArray[i].ID = "ContactBtn" + i;
            btnArray[i].Width = 295;
            btnArray[i].Height = 50;
            btnArray[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            btnArray[i].CssClass = "contacts";
            btnArray[i].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnContactBtn_Click);
            btnArray[i].Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        }

    } // end of InstantiateBtns()
```

Comment: thanks, but yes, i am recreating the buttons after a postback. the pageControls variable in my code keeps the dynamically created buttons, and onclick functions of these buttons work fine. The problem is, i have a modal popup and save button of this modal popup also is triggered, but when save button is clicked, there is no postback, Page_Load is not called

Comment: Ok, are you creating the save button when the page is first loaded by either creating it in the Page_Load event or calling a method from the Page_Load event?

Comment: Is the statement you have place above "b.Attributes.Add("onclick", "popWin()");" the event you are trying to fire? If so try what I have shown in my post "  btnArray[i].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnContactBtn_Click);"? I know this is method of adding a click event is correct because I use it regularly.